# Where is the random number generator in the .value() method?

Tags: sql, xml, security

While running an HP Fortify scan, I'm getting the following insecure randomness warning:

```
The random number generator implemented by value() cannot withstand a cryptographic attack.
```

The line in question is in a T-SQL stored procedure, using the `value()` method to extract a value from XML:

```
SELECT t.c.value('@RequestId[1]', 'BIGINT') AS RequestId
```

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type), there's no reason that this should be using a random value generator unless it's deep within the implementation. Does anyone know where this is being used and whether or not this is a real security issue or a false positive?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this same issue a few times with Fortify, and I believe that it is a false positive.  Fortify somehow thinks value() in t-sql is returning a random value, and I have not found any evidence of this (and neither did you).

If I am wrong (I don't think I am), then you can ask whether your application needs secure randomness for that statement, because it may not.  Fortify is a tool that does not understand context, so all it can do is raise a flag when it sees insecure randomness without understanding whether secure randomness is needed.  A skilled code reviewer who knows enough context about the application and what is happening here should be able to say whether secure randomness is needed or not here (if randomness is involved at all -- which is in doubt).

Keep in mind that Fortify, just like any other security tool, is not perfect.  Even if we take context out of the equation, this is not the only example of an issue raised by the tool that in my mind is just not a real issue.